# Why does Voldemort use this spell?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, the-deathly-hallows-2

In the last Harry Potter movie, Harry surrenders himself to Voldemort in the Forbidden Forest. Then, in order to finish him for good, he uses *Avada Kedavra*. Why is this spell used? He knew Harry once survived it. Why not use a more destructive spell like *Confringo* which could destroy him to pieces?

Comment: Can Confringo be used on humans ? (were there any instances of it being used on humans directly ?) I don't think it effects humans. If it did.. it would be an Unforgivable curse. Right ?

Comment: well, he can always aim for the shirt.

Comment: Would Voldemort stoop so low ? He's all about grand speeches, soliloquy and definitely some bad ass  (but bad) spells.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Voldemort had something to prove FOR himself and TO his followers. Voldemort had figured out that it was love that made the first use of the killing curse fail. But his followers had their doubts, and Voldemort realized this as well.

So Voldemort made it a point to kill Harry himself, and to do it publicly so that his followers will conclude that Harry is not "the chosen one". And it had to be the same curse that failed the first time so that he could prove that his powers were the best in history (and that Harry really was not immune to the curse). But he did not know what Dumbledore knew.

Dumbledore, being just as extraordinary in his intellect as he was as a wizard, knew Voldemort's intentions. He had painstakingly put all the puzzle pieces together. And he had a plan to defeat Voldemort if Harry did exactly the right moves. Dumbledore figured out that Voldemort would in fact do what he did, AND that it would not work on Harry because he possessed part of Voldemort's soul. Furthermore, once done, that part of Voldemort's soul would be destroyed while not actually hurting Harry. That is why Dumbledore instructed Harry to surrender himself.

Harry and his friends made the rest of it work.

Comment: Well, after Harry suddenly wake up and attack Nagini he uses the confringo. If only he uses it earlier he will not die. :D

Comment: @KissMe, you are right. Also, someone else could have killed Harry, and Harry would have really died. But Voldemort had an I-am-the-best-who-ever-lived attitude. That made him set in his ways in the sense that, from his point of view, there was only one "perfect" way to deal with Harry Potter. And Voldemort viewed himself as "perfect" (or nearly so). That predictability was his fatal weakness that allowed a genius like Dumbledore to orchestrate Voldemort's defeat.

Answer (score 5):

Another point of view is that Voldemort thinks that Harry survived to the Avada Kedavra because of the protection given by his mother sacrifice.
In the Goblet of fire, when Voldemort return, he says

> It was love. You see, when dear, sweet Lily Potter gave her life for
>   her only son. . . . . .she provided the ultimate protection. l could
>   not touch him. It was old magic. Something l should have foreseen. But
>   no matter, no matter. Things have changed. l can touch you. . . . .
>   .now.

So I guess that he is sure that now, without that "Old magic", the Avada Kedavra will work well.

Comment: Yes, combine that with their first encounter, where physical contact with Harry destroyed the body he was inhabiting, he was confident after touching Harry in the cemetery that Harry was no longer protected.

Answer (score 1):

Voldemort used Avada Kedavra because it was the strongest unforgivable curse. No one can survive it unless very strong magic protects that person. In the first movie of the series, Harry survived the spell because his mother protected him with a very old spell where her death will protect Harry. And because of that spell, Voldemort couldn't touch Harry. But in *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* movie, Voldemort was back with Harry's blood which broke his mother's spell, and Voldemort could touch him. So Voldemort could easily finish Harry with the strongest unforgivable curse as the protection was no more. So Voldemort thought to finish Harry with this curse once and forever.
Moreover, Voldemort has an evil mind and mostly evil minds like to curse rather than do a destructive magic like confringo which is used by many good wizards. Harry Potter has done this magic more than once. So he liked to do a more evil magic which is generally used by the Death Eaters. So he used this unforgivable curse which can't be changed once it is done.

Comment: Nice answer. Please realize also that Voldemort would not be able to kill Harry because part of Voldemort's soul attached itself to Harry when the original Avada Kadavra failed (when Harry was a baby).

Comment: Yes @John.But Voldemort didn't know that.Only Professor Dumbledore realized that.So Voldemort thought Avada Kedrava will be strong enough to kill harry once and forever.

Comment: You are correct of course. I was only commenting because of the sentence: "So Voldemort could easily finish Harry...". Perhaps you meant to say "So Voldemort thought he could easily finish Harry...".